# Is it possible to give a shortcut to a specific screen layout?

Tags: python, interface

I know about the shortcut Ctrl + Left / Right arrow to switch between the screen layouts, but that forces you to go through all of them if you have many.

I'd like to give a screen layout (not only to an editor) a single shortcut like:

F1 = 3D View Full

F2 = Animation

F3 = Compositing
...

Is it possible via User preferences > Input?
If so, what is the exact code operator I should put in the key map? (like "screen.screen_set" but with the specific name of my screen layout)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An operator to set screen by name.

```
import bpy    
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class SCREEN_OT_set_by_name(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Change Screen by Name"""
    bl_idname = "screen.set_by_name"
    bl_label = "Set Screen by Name"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    name = StringProperty(default="",
                          description="Set the Screen by name")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.screen is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        to_screen = bpy.data.screens.find(self.name)
        if to_screen >= 0:
            # context.screen
            from_screen = bpy.data.screens.find(context.screen.name)
            delta = to_screen - from_screen
            if not delta:
                return {'CANCELLED'}
            sign = abs(delta) / delta
            delta = abs(delta)
            for i in range(delta):
               bpy.ops.screen.screen_set('INVOKE_DEFAULT', delta=sign)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SCREEN_OT_set_by_name)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SCREEN_OT_set_by_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.screen.set_by_name(name="Default")
```

[image]
*Keymap F1 to change to "Default" screen.*

Comment: Thank you batFINGER, but I'm not very good with scripts and I'm not sure what to do with this code.I tried to paste it in the text editor but when I hit "Run Script" it says "Python script fail, look in the console for now..."

Comment: Look in the console then, and post what the error message was. If you are on Windows OS just use *Window > Toggle System Console*.

Comment: Sorry it was a cut n paste error, missing `import bpy`.  Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfectly.

There is only one small thing, if I press "F1, F2, F1", the screen layouts switch perfectly, but when I press consecutively "F1, F1", I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File"\Text.001", line 22, in execute ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
location: <unknown loccation>:-1

Can this error message be removed?

Comment: Fixed.  Was sure I put that check in in the first place... Copy / Paste run again.

Comment: No more error indeed. What is the best way to make this script part of my permanent configuration? (so I don't have to set it up each time). Do I have to make it as an add-on or could I simply store it as a text file somewhere in the Blender installation folders?